# Unicode characters between \u0003 and \u00ff

Tags: unicode

I have a piece of Java code that is checking it is between two unicode characters:

```
LA(2) >= '\u0003' && LA(2) <= '\u00ff'
```

I understand that `\u0003` represents `END OF TEXT` and `\u00ff` is `LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS`, but what lies between these points? (what is it checking that LA(2) is?)

e.g. is it all Latin characters, or number characters, or characters with accents, all ascii characters, or something else?

Comment: Look it up yourself on the [Unicode code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Latin 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1#Codepage_layout) minus the code points U+0000, U+0001 and U+0002. This includes the usual stuff that can be found on the US keyboard, plenty of control characters (below U+0020 and between U+007F and U+009F) and a few other Latin characters that can be used to write the majority of Western European languages.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following ranges are declared:

```
0000 - 007F C0 Controls and Basic Latin
0080 - 00FF C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement
```

To check out which unicode value represents which character, I advise to have a look at one of the following links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters
- http://unicode.org/

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic latin1 character set except the first 3 codes.

```
0x0000 - 0x007F : Basic Latin (128)
0x0080 - 0x00FF : Latin-1 Supplement (128)
```

The code probably checks whether the character can be output as a single byte char (latin1 encoded).

Comment: The character set is called Latin 1, Basic Latin is simply the ASCII code block in Unicode, as you noted. But there is no such thing as “Basic Latin 1”.

Comment: I don't know why you wrote that

Comment: Because the terminology you used in the first sentence of your answer is unclear and technically incorrect.